# Get fisrt 100 href with xpath and php

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I write this code to get href's (links) from an web resource... that resource have more than 1000 links ...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.domain.me/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@class='media-body']/p/a[2]/@href");
$output = array();
```

How I can get with xpath - etc. first 100 links from www.domain.me , or links from 100. to 200. ... Is there any way to get links beetween 100. AND 200 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) the results:

$links = array_slice($links, 100, 100);

Comment: but I have then: foreach($entries as $e) {  
 so how to foreach from 100 to 200 ...

Comment: There is another answer using xpath magic, but if you still interested in this way, that would be: $my_entries = array_slice($entries, 100, 100); foreach($my_entries as $e) { ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use position function of xpath

```
$entries = $xpath->query("//div[@class='media-body']/p/a[position()>=$start and position() <= $end]/@href");
```